# Determine $\rho$ in such a way that $\int\int_B xydxdy$ has maximum value.*

Tags: integration, analysis

I have a difficulty solving this exercise. I set it up but not sure how to continue.

*Let $\Omega={x^2+y^2-2x \leq 99}$ and consider $B$ a generic ball of radius $1$ and center $\rho$ in the edge of $\Omega.$
Determine $\rho$ in such a way that $ \displaystyle \iint_B xy ~dx ~dy~$ has maximum value.*

So long as $\rho$  is in the edge of $\Omega$, $\rho= (x', y')$ such that $x'^2 + y'^2 -2x' = 99$.

So $B=(x,y) \text { in } \mathbb{R}^2 \text { such that }  (x-x')^2+(y-y')^2 \leq 1$

Turning to polar coordinates

$x = \rho \cos t + x'$
and
$y = \rho \sin t + y'$

$dx=-\rho \sin t$ and $dy = \rho \cos t$

with $\rho \in [0,1]$ and $t \in [0, 2\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

$f = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \rho \cdot(x' + \rho \cos t) (y' + \rho \sin t) ~ d\rho ~dt $

As integral of $\sin t$ and $\cos t~$ over $~t \in (0, 2\pi)$ is zero, the integral can be simplified and we finally get $~ f = \pi x' y'$

Now we know that $~x'^2 + y'^2 - 2x' = 99$

$$ \implies (x'-1)^2 + y'^2 = 100$$

Converting to polar coordinates,
$x' = 1 + 10 \cos \theta, y' = 10 \sin\theta, ~\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$

$f = 10 \pi (\sin\theta + 5 \sin 2\theta)$

Now to find critical points,  $f_{\theta} = 10 \pi (\cos\theta + 10 \cos 2\theta) = 0$

Solve the quadratic, $20 \cos^2\theta + \cos\theta - 10 = 0$ to find critical points and you should be able to get the maximum of $f$.